# How to logout on app exit in Silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, web-services, exit

I have a silverlight application with custom form authentication.
How i can logout application when the browser window is closed?

I tried something like this:

```
 public App()
    {
        Startup += ApplicationStartup;
        Exit += Application_Exit;

        UnhandledException += ApplicationUnhandledException;
        var webContext = new WebContext {Authentication = new FormsAuthentication()};
        ApplicationLifetimeObjects.Add(webContext);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ApplicationStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Resources.Add("WebContext", WebContext.Current);
        RootVisual = new MainPage();
    }

    private void Application_Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebContext.Current.Authentication.Logout(false);
    }
```

but this didn't work. Ewery time I close the browser, I receive the exception **An AsyncCallback threw an exception** without any details.

How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you could call an ajax call on the page with onbeforeunload, forget the idea to call logoff with silverlight whilst it is closing.